# Display a Single Occurrence

Tags: powershell

This is my list:

```
Apple
Apple
Apple
Pear
Orange
Pear
Apple
Apple
Apple
Apple
Apple
Pear
Kiwi
Kiwi
Kiwi
```

So my final list would only display a single occurrence of each fruit

```
Apple
Orange
Pear
Kiwi
```

If there are only 4 elements then a simple function will do.  But I have over a dozen elements in my list which periodically changes so  hardcode the list is out of the question.  Is there a built in function (cmdlet) or any other methods that I can do to only display a single occurrence of each element in the list.  So it would strip away any duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: $A = $(foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\Test1\File1.txt) {$line.tolower().split(" ")}) | sort | Get-Unique

Comment: Depending on PowerShell version, `Get-Unique`.  A common approach: `$List | Select-Object -Unique`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-Unique` cmdlet on a sorted list or the `-Unique` parameter on cmdlets like `Select-Object` or `Sort-Object`

Pre-sorted list with `Get-Unique`:

```
$list = @('Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear')
$list | Get-Unique

Apple 
Kiwi  
Orange
Pear
```

Using `Sort-Object -Unique`:

```
$list = @('Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi') 
$list | Sort-Object -Unique

Apple
Kiwi
Orange
Pear
```

Alternatively, you could use `Group-Object` and take the `Name` property of each group. Note that this method does not require a sort so will keep the list in the order that the elements were first encountered.

```
$list = @('Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi', 'Kiwi') 
($list | Group-Object).name

Apple
Pear
Orange
Kiwi
```

Comment: `Get-Unique` requires a sorted list

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them in the same order?

There are *nix command utilities you could use to do this:

```
type mylist.txt | sort | uniq
```

I don't know if they are already part of the windows subsystems for linux or not.  But I know you can find windows versions online.